# 3D PDF figure generation

Tags: 3d, media9

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis in LaTeX and just a few days ago I found that pdf allows for 3D figures insertion (using the media9 package).

I've managed to add an object I found online into the document, but it needs to be in `.u3d` or in `.prc`. I haven't seen an open source program that can help you exporting to those formats, but I did find: SimLab Composer. You can have a trial, but after that you have to pay 200$ :(.

Please, can anyone tell me an effective workflow or software to convert from 3D file to `.u3d` or `.prc`? :)

Answer (score 3):

The [asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) program converts an `.asy` file (which has a C - style language) into `.prc` files.

Comment: But I don't have an .asy file. What I have is an `.obj`/`.step`/`.stl` (from CATIA), which I want to convert to `.prc`. Can you detail it further if that is possible? (Also Asymptote is really confusing)

Comment: @Hrvi Can't Catia export an .u3d object?

Comment: @pluton Probably requiring an expensive plug-in.

Comment: @pluton I use V5R19 and sadly it doesn't support saving in that format :(

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it was an export format by default but I do not use Catia...

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a 3D model in another format, you can use [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net/) to convert it to U3D. It should accept input in all common formats. (stl/obj/...)

Make sure that you use the latest version: MeshLab's U3D exporter used to have some issues, but in the latest release notes (MeshLab 2020.07) they write

> u3d exporter is now more stable and works on every platform;

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Marcel Krüger. I've tried it, but sadly in the saving process it just keeps crashing again and again.